# What is example.com/rss/catalog/notifystock/ for?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, adminhtml, stock, rss

I've noticed in some server logs that a lot of bots are trying to guess admin login credentials via this route.

I hope one of you can tell me **what this RSS feed is used for and why admin credentials are needed**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the feed you can get from the backend under **Catalog > Manage Products > Notify Low Stock RSS**:

[image]

It is a RSS feed that notifies you for out of stock products.